# Redirect 301 - redirect pages with specific word in address

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a big problem with .htaccess redirect. I have to do redirect from address contain specific word or number (some pages with word, some with numbers). This parts of address are in different places so i need universal solution.

I tried this method but it isn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)number-or-word(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule https://newdomain.com/new-specific-adress [L,R=301]
```

P.S. I change domain too.

Do you have any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing the first argument to `RewriteRule` which is the regex to match:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)number-or-world(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com/new-specific-adress [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help! Unfortunately it's still not working. 
Maybe the problem is that there is no dynamic addresses?

Comment: What isn’t working about it? Does it not redirect or do you get an error? Do you have anything else in your htaccess file?

Comment: Does it not redirect. In htaccess file i had nothing more than is required to start mod rewrite.

Comment: @ŁukaszRosicki What's an example URL you're using?